# IOS: Displaying multiple annotations on map by name

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

In my project i have to display multiple annotations on `MapView`. The response i received from server is displaying  Latitude and Longitude).
Someone please suggest me code how i display multiple annotations on map as i put all address values in an `NSArray`.Output of My array in console is as below:

array name : arrayforlocation

```
(
"[39.4835647,-119.7310213]",
"[42.5629668,-114.4608711]",
"[45.5064511,-122.7756216]",
"[40.2338438,-111.6585337]",
"[45.7832856,-108.5006904]"
)
```

also please suggest some code to split this array into two arrays for separate latitude and longitude values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest, you ask your web service developer to send locations (in form of latitude and longitude) as well, if they can't then you can request via [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html) (or can use some other accurate service provider like [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/) or a [library](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVGeocoder)) to get latitude and longitude information for a particular address which you have. Only after that, you will be able to show pin for particular address on a map.

E.g.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Your Address String" 
    completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
         for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
         {
             // Process the placemark.
             NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude];
             NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude];
         }
}];
```

And then, you can follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html) to show annotations on your map.

Comment: ok if i have the lat and longitude of the locations in array. what code i have to use

Comment: Then you only need to create annotations and then show it on to the map.

Comment: please check my updated question now i have the output data in latitude and longitude form. please suggest me code to display annotations

Comment: can you please suggest me codes to split my array into two arrays which shows separate latitude and longitude values. and also please upvote my question so that i can ask more questions

Comment: You should not ask different question which are belongs to a single question query. If you have another question then you can always ask if you are sure that "it wasn't previously asked." To check for it, google your problem or while asking lookout for already asked suggestions.

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap, why you unaccepted this answer? Didn't you find it useful?

Comment: ohh dat was by mistake. it works for me also please upvote my ques as i am now unable to ask new question coz of no positive score(upvote) in my this question please

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to add annotations on map view :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
location.latitude = (double) 44.4758;
location.longitude = (double) -73.2125;
span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
span.longitudeDelta=0.2;
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"BCA" andCoordinate:location];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];



themapView = [[MapView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:themapView.view];
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: please check my question i have an array in which there are 5 location values. those values are to be shown on map

Comment: You can loop these location values to create multiple annotations, add them into an array and then reload your map with those annotations.

Comment: can you please suggest me how i split my array into two arrays which shows separate latitude and longitude values

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by myself.
Here is my solution:
firstly i create separate arrays for latitude and longitude then 
in .m file i put the following codes

```
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c  titleee:(NSString *) t  subTitle:(NSString *)timed time:(NSString *)tim
{
    self.coordinate=c;
    self.time=tim;
    self.subTitle=timed;
    self.titleee=t;
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c titleee:(NSString *)t
{
    self.coordinate=c;
    self.titleee=t;
    return self;
}


-(void)showaddressonmap
{
    for ( int i=0; i<[latArray count]; i++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;

        coord.latitude=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[latArray objectAtIndex:i]] floatValue];
        coord.longitude=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          [longArray objectAtIndex:i]] floatValue];
        MKCoordinateRegion region1;
        region1.center=coord;
        region1.span.longitudeDelta=20 ;
        region1.span.latitudeDelta=20;
        [mapvw setRegion:region1 animated:YES];

        NSString *titleStr =[locationName objectAtIndex:i] ;
        NSLog(@"title is:%@",titleStr);

        NearestResultDiagnose *  annotObj =[[NearestResultDiagnose alloc]initWithCoordinate:coord titleee:titleStr];
        [mapvw addAnnotation:annotObj];
    }
}
```

And in my .h file i put the following codes

```
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *titleee;
    NSString *subTitle;
    NSString *time;


}
@property (nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *titleee;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subTitle;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *time;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c  titleee:(NSString *) t  subTitle:(NSString *)timed time:(NSString *)tim;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c titleee:(NSString *)t;
```

and synthesize the properties